# 301 Redirect in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone tell me what this 301 redirect is actually doing? Thanks.

```
<?php
if ( wm_option( 'layout-breadcrumbs-portfolio-page' ) )
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( wm_option( 'layout-breadcrumbs-portfolio-page' ) ), 301 );
else
    wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 );

exit;
?>
```

Comment: looks like it is saying if the results of wm_option is not false or null, take that value and fetch the permalink of a page having that value as an ID, then redirect to it. Otherwise, kick user back to home page. Check the permalink doc here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink - have you tried print_r(wm_option( 'layout-breadcrumbs-portfolio-page' )) to see what you get?

Comment: where do I substitute 

print_r(wm_option( 'layout-breadcrumbs-portfolio-page' ))

Comment: how about right where this code is? just comment out what's there and throw the print_r in there. also add die(); after it to kill further processing on the page.

Comment: Ok, I put it in. Do I need to clear cache?

Comment: This is the test staging: http://rscontent.wpengine.com

Comment: what is the benefit of this? I'm a noob so be gentle.

Comment: I don't know what the benefit is exactly since this snippet could reside anywhere. In theory, it is a provision against finding dead links but it looks like it is only checking one ID. without knowing what the wm_option function returns it is hard to say.